# Spring AOP: How to intercept inner class?

Tags: java, spring, aop

My Class:

```java
@Aspect
public class ServiceAspect {
    @Before("execution(public * com.test.server.support.service.*.Client.*(..))")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("....");
    }
}
```

spring-config.xml Content Only:

```xml
<context:annotation-config/>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.client.support">
    <context:include-filter type="aspectj" expression="com.test.client.support.aspect.ServiceAspect"/>
</context:component-scan>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.manager"/>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

I hope in this way can then `xxx.Client` each class the following method call, the connection is automatically created.

When the current operation of the project, AOP no response.

However, if theBefore

```
("execution (public * com.test.server.support.service.*.Client.*(..))")
```

IntoPointcut

```
("@within (org.springframework.stereotype.Controller)")
```

, you can enter before method

Note: Client class is automatically generated Thrift IDL.

Comment: With this description is really hard to tell the problem, but I have one question: Can you tell me concrete, fully qualified class names the methods of which you want to intercept? Are the classes directly in the `com.test.server.support.service` package? One subpackage below? Two? More?

Comment: com.test.server.support.service has many classes, each class has an internal Client class. I want to intercept all methods Client under.（com.test.server.support.service.Role.Client. Client is the Role of the inner class)

Comment: For me this works, no matter if `Client` is a static or non-static inner class. I tried with pure AspectJ though, not with Spring AOP. But the pointcut syntax and matching algorithms should be the same. So unless you have a Spring configuration problem I do not know what the problem could be. Maybe you can update the question by posting the `Role` source code including the inner class. Don't forget package name and imports. Please also add those two to the aspect.

Comment: com.test.server.support.service.* In other jar file. spring aop class other jar file does not take effect, how can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Spring AOP only works on public methods of classes declared as Spring Beans. I guess your inner classes probably are not Spring Beans. So either you should

- refactor your code to get rid of inner classes or
- make your inner classes Spring Beans or
- switch from Spring AOP to full AspectJ (`<context:load-time-weaver/>` instead of `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>`), see [Spring documentation, chapter 9.8](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj).

**Update:** The `within()` pointcut in AspectJ also encompasses inner classes, this is documented. If and how that also applies to Spring AOP, I do not know.